# Как разделить соединившиеся права двух Django проектов?

Tags: django, django-admin

У меня есть 2 разных Django проекта, с собственными окружениями. Подключаются к одной базе данных и их разрешения слились в одну таблицу. Теперь в админ панеле одного проекта я вижу разрешения сразу 2 проектов. Как это пофиксить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть  таблица в базе auth_permission  - это оттуда. Удалите с нее значения ручками, будет Вам счастье.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Это же значит, что у одного из проектов слетят разрешения? Нельзя как-то в одном из проектов прописать, чтобы они были не в auth_permission, а в другой таблице(как db_table у моделей)?

Comment: Эти разрешения контролируются бэкэнд программистом. Если он привязывает их к id например  в этой таблице - да, слетят. Если привязка к codename - нет, не слетят. Сама джанга там где это надо привязывает к codename, потому при удалении только дубликатов всё продолжит работать как надо.

Comment: Проще говоря, если есть привязка к ForeignKey или какое нибудь ManyToMany - нельзя просто так удалять, нужно сначала проверить....

Comment: Я новичок на позиции бэкенд. Как мне можно проверить к айди привязано или codename?)

Comment: Для начала надо выяснить - используется ли это вообще :) В 99% случаев не используют это, но как говорится - бывают исключения. Поищите по исходникам импорты данной модели. Если их нет - удаляйте дубликаты смело.

Comment: Вообще используются по паре кастомных прав в каждом. И я всё не могу успокоиться, неужели нельзя изменить дефолтную таблицу для этого дела?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100243/discussion-between-pavel-kutsubin-and--).

Comment: Может с этим поможет SITE_ID ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#site-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На каком-то форуме нашёл, что в джанге изначально не было такой фичи. Изменять это слишком фундаментально и вряд-ли эта фича появится.